# Object Detection - Google Colab - YOLO

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo

been working on an object detection project lately in python where this thing works such that it will be used to detect chicken in real time using webcam. Google Colab is used as the virtual environment and I have custom trained the model myself. The thing is, it is supposed to show a preview window of the frames from webcam in real time and shows bounding box around the detected subject while at the same time showing lines of log saying the object is detected. But my code below does not seem to work in that way: the webcam window preview is there but there are no log telling whether the object is detected or not just like how it is written in the code, hence, I can't identify the reason of the absence of bounding box in the video preview.

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
from base64 import b64decode
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import os

#load model
model_path = os.path.join('drive', 'MyDrive', 'sample_data', 'best.pt')
model = YOLO(model_path)  # load a custom model

desired_object_class = 'chicken'

while True:
    def update_frame(img_data):
        # Convert base64 image data to OpenCV format
        nparr = np.frombuffer(b64decode(img_data.split(',')[1]), np.uint8)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        # Perform object detection
        results = model(frame)

        # Display the resulting frame with bounding boxes
        frame_with_boxes = results.show()

        # Check if the desired object is detected
        desired_object_detected = False
        for label, confidence, box in zip(results.names, results.scores, results.xyxy):
            if label == desired_object_class and confidence > 0.5:  # Adjust confidence threshold 
                desired_object_detected = True
                break

        # Log whether the desired object is detected
        if desired_object_detected:
            print(f"{desired_object_class} detected!")
        else:
            print(f"{desired_object_class} not detected.")

        # Display the frame in the notebook
        cv2_imshow(frame_with_boxes)

    def init_camera():
        js_code = """
        const video = document.createElement('video');
        document.body.appendChild(video);

        // Activate webcam and send frames to Python
        async function initCamera() {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
            video.srcObject = stream;

            // Callback for each frame
            const onFrame = () => {
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
                canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                // Convert the frame to base64 and send it to Python
                const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9);
                google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction('update_frame', [imgData], {});
                requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
            };

            // Start capturing frames
            video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                video.play();
                requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
            };
        }

        initCamera();
        """

        return Javascript(js_code)

    # Display the webcam feed using HTML and JavaScript
    display(init_camera())

    # Register the update_frame function with JavaScript
    display(Javascript('google.colab.output.setIframeHeightAuto(true)'))

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        print("Operation Ends")
        break
```

Appreciate any help from you guys. A programming newbie here btw.

Comment: You fail to tell us what is not working.

Comment: Thanks for informing, I've added in the problem.

Comment: Boil it down to the simplest case. Locally, run inference on a single image -- is it detecting like it should?  What command are you running?  Once you get that working, then try again but with a video instead of a static image.  Let us us the commands that works, and more importantly, where things fail along with any errors.

Comment: Fyi, they worked, it may be probably due to the coding for streaming on webcam I show here. I'm using google colab tho, so source='0' is not applicable in this case...